# калькулятор на Java, String

Tags: java, строки, калькулятор

Я делаю калькулятор и у меня есть переменная String которая берёт инфу из textArea и получается, после того как я нажал кнопку равно, она взяла инфу из полоски например (24+5) и мне надо что бы соответственно число 24 и 5 сложились в 29 и вывелось. Я думал это сделать вроде что, стринг в инт и потом обратно в стринг, но идея тупая (p.s. как я) 
будьте добры) Я только учусь)

Comment: Используйте подход, который описали: выражение полученное в виде String надо будет распарсить на числа и операторы, далее вычислить, а результат обратно  в String. Если хотите, чтобы калькуоятор вычислял выражения  более чем с одним оператором и при этом соблюдал порядок выполнения операторов - познакомьтесь с обратной польской записью. Распарсить строку отдельно на числа и операторы не так сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо примеры указывать в `int` либо же парсите строку в `int` через `Integer.ParseInt(Str);` `Str` - переменная `string` или строка.